# Using ReadProcessMemory with process module base address and offsets

Tags: c#, pointers, memory, process, memory-address

How does one read memory using a process module's base address and offsets? I have grabbed the desired module's base address with the following:

```
        Process process = Process.GetProcessesByName("process")[0];
        ProcessModule bClient;
        ProcessModuleCollection bModules = process.Modules;
        IntPtr processHandle = OpenProcess(0x10, false, process.Id);
        int firstOffset = 0xA4C58C;
        int anotherOffset = 0xFC;

        for (int i = 0; i < bModules.Count; i++)
        {
            bClient = bModules[i];
            if (bClient.ModuleName == "module.dll")
            {
                IntPtr baseAddress = bClient.BaseAddress;
                Console.WriteLine("Base address: " + baseAddress);
            }
        }
```

After that I added the first offset to the base address:

```
IntPtr firstPointer = IntPtr.Add(baseAddress, (int)firstOffset);
```

This gives me a pointer; 440911244 in this case.

I can use this pointer in Cheat Engine, for instance, to browse its memory region and find the value to which the `anotherPointer` points to but I don't find the proper way to add the offset to `firstPointer`, however.

My question is, do I have to use ReadProcessMemory just before adding the final `anotherOffset` to the pointer? If so, what is the proper way of using it in this case?

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool ReadProcessMemory(
IntPtr hProcess, 
IntPtr lpBaseAddress,
IntPtr lpBuffer, 
int dwSize, 
out IntPtr lpNumberOfBytesRead);
```

Comment: What is "anotherOffset"? What do you expect to read from the process' memory?

Comment: @KrzysztofBracha firstOffset points to a specific memory region and in there the anotherOffset points to a "float" I need to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the ReadProcessMemory lpBuffer paramater to:

```
byte[] lpBuffer,
```

then

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[sizeof(float)];
IntPtr bytesRead = IntPtr.Zero;

IntPtr readAddress = IntPtr.Add(baseAddress, firstOffset);
readAddress = IntPtr.Add(readAddress, anotherOffset)

ReadProcessMemory(processHandle, readAddress, buffer, buffer.Length, out bytesRead);

float value = BitConverter.ToSingle(buffer, 0);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I don't think it worked though; just adding the offsets to the base address just seems to point to the wrong location. Is it possible to add int-type offsets (hex) to the base address? EDIT: Seems like adding just one offset (firstOffset) to the base and reading the memory gives the right "temporary address". From there I need to go 0xFC further to find the final float.

Comment: I have updated  the answer, apologies for the mistake.